# How to access ng-model length outside a ng-repeat within a ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm struggling with a solution to get the length of an item in ng-repeat within a ng-repeat. I can only get the items.length if it is with the second ng-repeat. If I try to access it outside the child it renders nothing. So how to access the scope outside the parent ng-repeat?
example code:

```
    <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items">
        {{item.some.model}}
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="moreItem in moreItems">
                {{moreItem.someother.model}}
            </li>
            {{moreItem.someother.model.length}} does work
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

{{moreItem.someother.model.length}} Doesnt work
```

Comment: Should you example be "item.model" and "moreItem.model" instead of someother?  Your example code doesn't make sense.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, I was just trying to show simple example of what Im trying to do

Comment: Ok.  ng-repeat creates a new scope for each item, so outside of the element with ng-repeat, moreItem is not going to be defined, and there isn't really a way around that.

Answer (score 0):

$scope.parent is how you affect the parent scope. $scope.root is how you affect the root scope. Hope this helps!

Comment: So you are saying i can access the child scope like this:{{parent.moreItem.someother.model.length}} I have tried this already without success

Answer (score 0):

OK, thanks for the help, but I found an easy way to accomplish my task using jQuery. The problem was how to validate a form submit button if the length of the child ng-repeat scope.length === 0. But since you cannot access this child scope outside parent scope I just wrote simple jQuery like this and problem is solved:

```
    suppQuestCtrl.checkQuestions = function(){
            $timeout(function(){
                setInterval(function(){
                    var qLength = jQuery('li#questions-text');
                    if(qLength.length === 0){
                        jQuery('#save-button.btn.btn-save').addClass('disabled')
                    } else{
                        jQuery('#save-button.btn.btn-save').removeClass('disabled')
                    }
                },500)
            },500)
        }; suppQuestCtrl.checkQuestions();
```

Comment: This could probably be made into a directive though

Comment: Don't use the identity operator here, just use the equality operator. That's where you went wrong...